# .cpp compile time tracking in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, compilation

I have to track compile time of each .cpp in every project. Default time-tracking in `VS` can't be used for it because this tool tracks time for projects, not for every `.cpp`.

Have you any ideas how to do this?

Comment: never done this, but you could compile from the command line (`cl` I think is the VS compiler) each file into objects. That can be easily measured. So you basically would have to make a Makefile or a compile script

Comment: Wild idea here, write a fake `cl.exe` that invokes the real one passing it the command line arguments and logging its execution time.

Comment: you can also investigate if custom build step (or something like that) covers events for compilation start and end of each translation unit.

Comment: @SirDarius like your idea.

Comment: I was afraid of this.. Thanks a lot, bolov, SirDarius.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually not that difficult to do and is available in Visual Studio.  It's an undocumented feature (figures....) but works nicely to report on individual compile times.  Here's an example...

```
3>------ Build started: Project: SomeProject, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>  stdafx.cpp
3>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c1xx.dll)=1.468s
3>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c2.dll)=0.048s
3>  SortStringArray.cpp
3>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c1xx.dll)=0.030s
3>  Registry.cpp
3>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c1xx.dll)=0.026s
3>  PropertyRoot.cpp
3>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c1xx.dll)=0.255s
```

To enable this feature, you need to add the undocumented compile switch **/Bt** to the *C/C++ command line additional options* for each project you'd like to track.  For more information on what's available for timing, check out this [VC++ Team Blog Post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/01/vc-tip-get-detailed-build-throughput-diagnostics-using-msbuild-compiler-and-linker.aspx).